# Encoding a video from Unix Timestamps + ms

Tags: timestamps, ffmpeg, video-encoding

I have a sequence of images that were taken from a camera that have been saved in a naming convention that contains the unix timestamp as well as milliseconds. For instance, 1333351808430.jpg (I typed this out myself as it's on a different computer, so might by slightly wrong).

I would like to encode this into a video. I know how to if I were to just assume a frame--rate using ffmpeg or other tools. The problem is, sometimes there is a large gap between frames, or the frame-rate is variable depending on network traffic.

What I'd like to do is create an accurately timed video based on the timestamp information that we have. What is the best way forward?

Comment: I guess you can determine a target frame-rate, then "fill the gaps" using  duplicated or morphed or interpolated images.